# QT: QFileSystemModel _q_fileSystemChanged slot is executed on the UI thread which contradicts documentation

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

My UI is using QTreeView with QFileSystemModel to be able to select folders and files.  The documentation for QFileSystemModel says that file structure update is done on a seperate thread which would mean the UI would not be blocked.  However, this is not the case for me and I can't figure out the discreptency and how other people are not running into this issue.  After debugging, I noticed that QFileSystemModel _q_fileSystemChanged slot which takes most of the time is still executed on the main UI thread which makes sense.  The Questiong is how does the documentation claim than that it will not block the UI.  Is there a solution? Am I misunderstanding something?

To repro
 - Create a QTreeView with QFileSystemDataModel
 - Set root path to "" or "/"
 - Set breakpoint in QFileSystemModel _q_fileSystemChanged slot
 - Expand one of the drives after app loads

Problem:
 - The slot is called on the UI thread thus blocking the app until it finishes.

There are ways to make the file parser faster, but it I really need to execute on a seperate thread and notify when the data is populated and ready for QTreeView.

Thanks,
Innokenty

Comment: Is your application actually freezing when not debugging with a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes.  It is mostly and very noticable on mapped network shares because it has to query each item.  The code path is the same for mapped and regular drives.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason for this could be the icons. Within the `_q_fileSystemChanged()` slot `fileInfoGatherer.getInfo()` gets called which - among other things - resolves the icons for the paths. In it's current design `QFileIconProvider` uses `QIcon` to represent icons and `QIcon` can only be used in the UI thread. `QImage` seems to be the only class allowed to use in other threads, but I think it may be to expensive to use `QImage` in the background thread and convert it to an `QIcon` in the UI thread.

So it is possible that the platform implementation of `QFileIconProvider` is slow on network paths under some circumstances and therefore slows down the UI main thread.

I don't know if this is the source of your problem, but at least this should be the reason why `_q_fileSystemChanged()` is called within the UI thread.